# Voyager Golden Record

Tags: spacetime, satellites

Has there been any subsequent researches or any respond from deep outer space in any type of form with these images and sounds?

Comment: I would like to think that *if* there was a returned signal, it'd probably be among the greatest (scientific?) discoveries ever and would merit all sorts of media coverage.

Comment: My question might seem a bit ignorant for a physicist, but as an undergraduate student, my curiosity goes beyond limits. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Both Voyager I and II continue to actively transmit data and continue undisturbed on their trajectories.  If someone or something found the spacecraft and retrieved the record, an end of transmission or change in trajectory would be likely.  You can check the status of the Voyager missions at [the JPL site](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/).